# Minimize distance from a point to a hyperellipsoid

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

The point is outside the ellpsoid.
I've found many way to solve this problem.
[DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid.pdf)
[Distance-to-ellipse](https://www.spaceroots.org/documents/distance/distance-to-ellipse.pdf)
But I only found the numerical solution(by algorithm).
Is there have a Closed-form expression(N-Dimension) can solve this problem?
If it does not exist, how to prove it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Why do you say "**hyper**ellipsoid" in the title?